# How to differentiate between staging/production with a dynamic inventory?

Tags: ansible

I'm stuck. Googled the hell out of the Web and couldn't find an answer.

I've been using Ansible for years, but always with static inventories. To differentiate between different environments like staging and production, I used different static inventory files, `staging` and `production`, respectively. When I needed to provision staging servers, I'd do:

```
ansible-playbook site.yml -i staging
```

When I wanted to do the same for production, I'd do:

```
ansible-playbook site.yml -i production
```

Both staging and production need variables with different values, so I have `group_vars/staging` and `group_vars/production`. All good and according to best practices.

Now, I need to provision EC2 instances in AWS. I'm using [this AWS guide](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/guide_aws.html#provisioning). I have a playbook with two plays. The first is run against `localhost`, creates/finds required EC2 instances in AWS, and populates a group with `add_host`. The second play uses that group to run against the EC2 instances discovered in the first play. All according to that guide.

It all works great except one thing. I have no idea how to specify which environment to provision and hence the required variables are not being loaded from `group_vars/(staging|production)`. Basically, what I want is something similar to `-i (staging|production)` I used all these years with static inventories, but it seems that using `-i` doesn't make sense now since the inventory is dynamic. I want a way to be able to load variables from either `group_vars/staging` or `group_vars/production` based on an argument I pass to `ansible-playbook` when I run it.

How do I do that? What's the best practice?

Comment: Perhaps you could do something with separate playbooks? Something like production.yml and staging.yml. Those playbooks would then include site.yml, but also including their env specific vars.

Answer (score 4):

While I am not sure how to do it with ansible EC2 moduel as we don't use it to build boxes from ansible level, there is a simple way to get what you want with [ec2 external inventory script](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_dynamic_inventory.html#example-aws-ec2-external-inventory-script) and simple settings in your `inventories/main`. What you need to do is set up the `ec2.py` and `ec2.ini` inside of your `inventories` so it will be used as source of instances.  Make sure to uncomment `group_by_tag_keys = True` inside of `ec2.ini`.

Next step is to differentiate which instance goes where. While there are many selection methods available in `ec2.py`, I prefer to specifically tag each instance accordingly. So all my instances have a tag called `environment` which is filled accordingly (in your case it would be either staging or production). Then all is left is to handle it inside of your `inventories/main`, and here is a small example how to do it.

First you must define empty group for tags you want to use:

```
[tag_environment_staging]

[tag_environment_production]
```

so we can later reference to them. After that all there is left to do is specify those groups as children for appropriate stages. So after that our minimal file will look like that:

```
[tag_environment_staging]

[tag_environment_production]

[staging:children]
tag_environment_staging

[production:children]
tag_environment_production
```

And there you go. From now on every instance pulled from ec2 via dynamic inventory script that comes with environment tag will be matched to appropriate  config in `group_vars`. All you have to remember that when dealing with dynamic inventories you want your `-i` point at `inventories` directory rather than specific file for it to work right.

Comment: Sections like `[tag_environment_staging]` already assume that there are tagged instances. What if I want to use Ansible to actually *create* those tags and *tag* instances with them? To do that properly, I need some `env` variable set to `staging` *before* I even start fetching facts from AWS. Before I run my playbook, our AWS account is clean and there's nothing there.

Comment: Tagging itself is easy and [laid out neatly in documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/guide_aws.html#provisioning). Then of course you need to pass to the playbook what sort of stage you are deploying, which is a fairly simple use of extra_vars or env.

Comment: I have sets of variables — more than a dozen variables — for each environment. Do I pass each of them with `-e` each time I need to provision/deploy to each environment? That's exactly what the question is about: how do I make `group_vars/(staging|production)` magically included the way they do when using static inventories?

Comment: @ElnurAbdurrakhimov and that is what I've explained in the answer. When you have that dynamic inventory set up then during gathering facts of hosts from EC2 it will expose the machine tags (and other characteristics) as ansible groups that you can use.

Comment: Which machine tags? There're no tags nor EC2 instances in AWS yet. I got a fresh AWS account and want to provision it with Ansible. I need to be able to specify which environment I want to provision *when I run Ansible*. And based on that I'll then have information on which tags to create and tag EC2 instances with. What you're talking about is using information about *existing* tags and EC2 instances that have been created before. That's not what I need.

Comment: @ElnurAbdurrakhimov once you create them with tags they will be existing, won't they? And if you went ahead and tried that solution, you would see that it actually works.

Comment: Create them with which tags? That's the question. Tags values are different depending on the environment I want to provision. If I just want to provision staging, I want variables from `group_vars/staging` to be used. One of those variables is `env: staging`. And based on that information the EC2 instances that will be created will have that tag with that value. *The question is how do I explicitly specify that I want variables from `group_vars/staging` and not `group_vars/production` for each Ansible run*.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar problem with dynamic inventories but for Openstack. The solution I've come up with so far is to use an environment variable to specify whether I want to target the staging or production environment. It should be applicable to your case as well. In our setup `$OS_PROJECT_NAME` is either `stage` or `prod`. In `ansible.cfg` set

```
inventory = ./inventories/${OS_PROJECT_NAME}/openstack.py
```

Then we have environment specific group variables under

```
inventories/(stage|prod)/group_vars/
```

The drawback is you have to have the inventory script in two places or have it symlinked. Beware also that group_vars found relative to the playbook directory will still override the inventory group_vars.

Comment: This is the approach I found the best after days of looking on the Internet and reading the book... Weird thing is that this quite important aspect of Ansible is not well-documented.

Comment: So this config still returns *every* host (dev/stage/prod) into *every* environment, there are no changes to `openstack.py` itself? How do you target the individual VMs that are designated for dev/stage/prod?

Comment: No, we use different openstack projects for the different environments. So the inventory script only returns the hosts in the current environment